# Buying Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Web Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Probably this isn't the right place... but ill give it a try.

I want to buy Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Web Edition in order to remotly install it on the server.

The question is: Can i buy a licence in USA? and pay in dollars? or do i have to buy it in my country (Portugal)? However since the servers are in Germany, should i buy the licence in Germany?

(And if anyone know a good reseller i would apreciate)

Thx in advance

Comment: Try asking this on ServerFault, you're more likely to find good answers there for server licensing issues.

Comment: I think you must contact your local retailer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, ServerFault is a better place for this....

Where you buy your license is of little consequence. It is the location of the installation that determines how the EULA is applied.

So buy your software at the best price regardless of location.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this for free by signing up to Microsoft website spark - the license can be used in production environments.